# Firebase setOffline() and reading offline data (android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following situation:

1. User not registered, I save data while offline (Firebase setOffline())
2. Cannot read the local data (populate listview etc) - the *ValueEventListener* and *ChildEventListener* **dont fire**
3. I set setOnline() on Firebase instance
4. Data is synced with web and displayed (listeners fire)
5. I set setOffline() again.
6. I save local data and read local data, works (listeners fire)

Question:

**How to read local data stored BEFORE going online?**

Scenario is: User uses the android app offline and decides later to register

Scenario 1:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();  // <--------NOTE THIS

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(App.get().getUid()).child("items").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // THIS IS NOT FIRING
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        ...
    }
});
```

After Scenario 1 I change code to this and run:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();  // <--------NOTE THIS

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(App.get().getUid()).child("items").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // THIS IS FIRING. ALL GOOD
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        ...
    }
});
```

After this I change code to following and it works

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline(); // <--------NOTE THIS

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("users").child(App.get().getUid()).child("items").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // THIS IS FIRING. ALL GOOD
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I added 3 segments (code blocks).

- I execute first block - does not work
- Second block - works
- Third block - works

Here is a [gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/ramden/3addea21cf925ecd3c8c380f78679ad9).

Problem is that first block does not work before being online with setOnline()

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time parsing your description. Can you show the code that reproduces the problem as a snippet?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ramden/3addea21cf925ecd3c8c380f78679ad9

Comment: Thanks for the code. I added it to the question, because links tend to rot. Since you force the client to go offline in scenario 1 before it has a chance to synchronize any data, I indeed expect it to not fire `onDataChange()` in that scenario. In the 3rd fragment it *will* fire, because it has had a chance to synchronize data to the local cache.

Comment: Thanks for improving question. Is the answer then to let it sync first (empty) and the put to offline? This could be hard to implement as I have to make sure that it has synced at least once. Is that right?

Comment: Why are you explicitly trying to manage online/offline state? By doing this you're digging a hole that you may find it hard to get out of.

Comment: Idea is that user is not forced to login / register, but if he / she decides to do so that then the data is pushed to firebase, not before that. It seems like firebase is not well suited for this kind of requirement...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131992/discussion-between-ramden-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: If you want to avoid having the user sign-in, you can start off with Anonymous Authentication and then upgrade that to a email/password or social account later. But starting offline and only enabling synchronizing later is not an ideal way of working with the Firebase Database, which is primarily an online database that continues working offline.

Comment: I think this is definitely the official answer to my problem :)

Comment: Just a side question... Saying the user is anonymous and he leaves the app (never uses it again). Then the data he left will stay there forever? So I guess this is a flaw in design of Firebase (or a "catch") - the data of this "temporary" user will stay there forever altough it should never have landed there. Also think terms and conditions - data of a user not willingly accepted saving his private data online... I guess I have to solve this situation with a local database and firebase only AFTER registration, but this is definitely bad from my (honest) point of view

Comment: Would you mind to extract your comments in an answer so I could mark it as solved?

Comment: Done. But feel free to add a self-answer with better contents instead. Since it's been over two months, it is probably still clearer to you than it is to me at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you force the client to go offline in scenario 1 before it has a chance to synchronize any data, I indeed expect it to not fire `onDataChange()` in that scenario. In the 3rd fragment it will fire, because it has had a chance to synchronize data to the local cache.

But why are you explicitly trying to manage online/offline state? By doing this you're digging a hole that you may find it hard to get out of.

If you want to avoid having the user sign-in, you can start off with Anonymous Authentication and then upgrade that to a email/password or social account later.

Just keep in mind that starting offline and only enabling synchronizing later is not an ideal way of working with the Firebase Database, which is primarily an online database that continues working offline.